# Visual studio code volar volar.inlayHints.eventArgumentInInlineHandlers settings

Tags: vscode-extensions, volar

[image]

Interesting issue where I have 2 .vue files with code. One looks nice (no intrusive hints) but the other shows attached screen (ANNOYING AF). Note that this code is a direct lift from vue.org tutorial so it isn't my code. I found the config setting in defaultSettings.json HOWEVER its read only :).

Google comes back with no real answer to my problem so how do I solve this?

Tried editing the settings file where I could see this options exists but it's locked

Comment: no screen attached that I can see, but I think I have a similar problem so will look out for your answer!

Comment: thanks quilkin me too, ive spent about an hour looking today but to no avail so far! Thanks for the heads up on the lack of image too, i'll try to readd it

Answer (score 4):

PROBLEM SOLVED

For those of us new to VSC. Basically you open up settings.json (CTRL + SHIFT + P settings.json) which for me bought back an empty json file. I realised that maybe this is a global settings file that would override defaultSettings.json.

Simply adding this entry solved my problem: "volar.inlayHints.eventArgumentInInlineHandlers": false

Comment: You need to choose `user settings` after `CTRL + SHIFT + P` ; if you just choose the first settings file in the list, the default file gets displayed, which as you say is not editable